# Removing consecutive duplicate rows bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-manipulation, data-cleaning, gaps-and-islands

I have some `event` data that are grouped into `sessions`. In some cases there are consecutive duplicate events within those sessions which I'd like to remove. Is there a way to do this in `bigquery`?

E.g.

Initial table:

```
session   eventType   eventOrder
1         a           1
1         a           2     
1         b           3
2         b           1
2         a           2
2         b           3
```

Desired result:

```
session   eventType   eventOrder
1         a           1
1         b           3
2         b           1
2         a           2
2         b           3
```

Comment: How do you define *consecutive duplicate events*? as it is, this cannot be assessed from your dataset. You would need an indentity column for this to make sense (like an auto incremented colum): do you have such column?

Comment: eventOrder gives the order of the events. So basically remove any row that matches for session and eventType with the row below where the table is arranged by session and eventOrder

Comment: OK. Another question, are you looking for a `select` or a `delete` statement?

Comment: Looking for a select query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `lag()`. The idea is to compare the current event type to the previous value for the same session, and eliminate records where they match:

```
select session, eventType, eventOrder
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lag(eventType) over(partition by session order by eventOrder) lag_eventType
    from mytable t
) t
where lag_eventType is null or eventType != lag_eventType
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution! Thanks for that!